# With the new GSM publishing flow, how long does it take for the add-on code changes to a be available to the end-users?

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

I published an update for my Google Form Add-on the last Dec 16, 2019 1:30 pm.

The changes were only made available to the end-users via GSuite Marketplace on Dec 18, 2019 around 5:30 am (1.5 days).

This was not the same experience for older patches. The previous release was last Oct 14, 2019 which only took about 10 minutes for the update to appear in the GSuite Marketplace. It's usually around that timing for earlier developments as well.

Is it possible to know if this will be the case for future releases as well?

```
Here are some config info for my add-on:
Visibility: Everybody in domain
Oauth scopes since the first release (Aug 2019):
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms.currentonly
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.scriptapp
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.send_mail
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until recently G Suite Marketplace add-ons were (partially) synchronized from the corresponding Chrome Web Store add-on. In particular the script version was synchronized. This process took about two days.

However, with the new publishing flow it's no longer needed to publish or update the Chrome Web Store add-on. All changes should be done in the G Suite Marketplace SDK and they take effect immediately. See https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/update-editor-addons.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried to do another publish and the update was almost immediate.